# MySQL, delete inno table doesnt reduce table size

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an innodb table with big table size (around 7GB),
I already delete about 80% of its rows,
The problem is the table size remains the same,

The innodb_file_per_table is ON,

How do I shrink the table size so it reflect the actual condition and save more disk space ?

Comment: Already answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24963/42478

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

If you built the table with `innodb_file_per_table=ON`, then you can do `OPTIMIZE TABLE` now.  (Be sure it is still `ON`.)

If `=OFF`, then the table is in the tablespace file `ibdata1` and the only way to return the space to the OS is by dumping *all* tables, removing ibdata1, then reloading the dump.  This is tedious and risky.  Meanwhile, the free space created by the `DELETEs` will be used by future `INSERTs`, etc.

More [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) of big deletes.